# How to browse back (cd ..) to parent until find a specific folder?

Tags: git, shell, terminal, parent, cd

I'm often browsing deep in my Git repository folder structure via terminal and I would like to navigate back until reach the root folder who contain the `.git` folder.

For example:

`cd ./a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h/i`

In order to return back to the `a` folder parent, the Git local repository root I would need to execute:

`cd ../../../../../../../../..`

How would I be able to return to the root folder without many `../`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with the following command:

```
cd `git rev-parse --show-toplevel`
```

Thanks to jthill for the updated version.

Comment: Don't do this, use ``cd `git rev-parse --show-toplevel` `` instead. The git dir isn't necessarily at the work tree top (for instance, submodules).

Comment: Awesome! Thanks @padawin

Answer (score 0):

Create a `sh` file at your home folder: `$ vim ~/.back2root.sh` and paste the script below:

```
while [ ! -d $(pwd)/.git ]
do
        cd ..
done
ls -ahl
```

You can also define a Git alias:

`$ git config --global alias.back2root '!~/.back2root.sh'`

And call only:

`$ git back2root`

Comment: This does not work if your current folder is a symlink into a subfolder of a git repo. `cd ..` is then executed infinitely.

Comment: @ByteHamster thanks! Would you suggest an improvement?

Comment: I don't know anything better. I guess the answer by padawin (asking git for the path) should be more reliable than doing it manually.